# Error when joining a Minecraft server :Message: Connection timed out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Everytime I try to join a server, it says this following error: Message: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information:. For some reason, it only happens with Aternos servers. I have tried to flush my DNS cache, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting a few seconds between opening the server list and joining the server.

If that doesn't help, you have internet problems, which could have a lot of different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `-Dfml.readTimeout=120` JVM argument when running Minecraft?  This should give Minecraft more time to download stuff from the server, and make a connection.  By default Minecraft will only wait 30s.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the answer is reloading; based on what I've had happened to me!

Comment: "Sometimes"? Care to expand upon that?